# Reprojection with gdal.Warp doesn't work

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp, python-3

I am trying to reproject a raster. I have tried gdal.Warp and it doesn't work.

> RuntimeError: Cannot find coordinate operations from 'EPSG:6257' to 'EPSG:6686'.

Working in Python 3, Windows 64bit

- GDAL  3.0.2
- proj  6.2.1

EPSG source Projection is 6257

```
PROJCS["MAGNA-SIRGAS / Medellin urban grid",
    GEOGCS["MAGNA-SIRGAS",
        DATUM["Marco_Geocentrico_Nacional_de_Referencia",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6686"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4686"]],
    PROJECTION["Colombia_Urban"],
    PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",6.22920888888889],
    PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-75.5648869444444],
    PARAMETER["False easting",835378.647],
    PARAMETER["False northing",1180816.875],
    PARAMETER["Projection plane origin height",1510],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6257"]]
```

I want to reproject to the following projection (which is the proj of a vector):

EPSG destination Projection is 6686

```
PROJCS["MAGNA-SIRGAS / Medellin urban grid",
    GEOGCS["MAGNA-SIRGAS",
        DATUM["Marco_Geocentrico_Nacional_de_Referencia",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6686"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["IGAC_Plano_Cartesiano"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",835378.647],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",1180816.875],
    PARAMETER["Longitude_Of_Center",-75.5648869444444],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Center",6.22920888888889],
    PARAMETER["Height",1510],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```

I tried:

```
input_raster = os.path.join(geotiff_path, 'aoi1.tif')
output_raster = os.path.join(geotiff_path, 'aoi1_reproj.tif')

gdal.Warp(output_raster,input_raster,dstSRS='EPSG:6686')
```

Any ideas? Thanks

EDIT:

when running from the command line:

```
(rio) C:\Users\xxxxxx>projinfo -s epsg:6257 -t epsg:6686

Candidate operations found: 1
-------------------------------------
Operation n┬░1:

unknown id, Inverse of Medellin urban grid + Ballpark geographic offset from MAGNA-SIRGAS to JGD2011 + Japan Plane Rectangular CS zone XVIII, unknown accuracy, World, has ballpark transformation

PROJ string:
Error when exporting to PROJ string: Unsupported conversion method: Colombia Urban

WKT2_2018 string:
CONCATENATEDOPERATION["Inverse of Medellin urban grid + Ballpark geographic offset from MAGNA-SIRGAS to JGD2011 + Japan Plane Rectangular CS zone XVIII",
    SOURCECRS[
        PROJCRS["MAGNA-SIRGAS / Medellin urban grid",
            BASEGEOGCRS["MAGNA-SIRGAS",
                DATUM["Marco Geocentrico Nacional de Referencia",
                    ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                ID["EPSG",4686]],
            CONVERSION["Medellin urban grid",
                METHOD["Colombia Urban",
                    ID["EPSG",1052]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",6.22920888888889,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8801]],
                PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-75.5648869444444,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8802]],
                PARAMETER["False easting",835378.647,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8806]],
                PARAMETER["False northing",1180816.875,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8807]],
                PARAMETER["Projection plane origin height",1510,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",1039]]],
            CS[Cartesian,2],
                AXIS["northing (N)",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                AXIS["easting (E)",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",6257]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        PROJCRS["JGD2011 / Japan Plane Rectangular CS XVIII",
            BASEGEOGCRS["JGD2011",
                DATUM["Japanese Geodetic Datum 2011",
                    ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                ID["EPSG",6668]],
            CONVERSION["Japan Plane Rectangular CS zone XVIII",
                METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
                    ID["EPSG",9807]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",20,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8801]],
                PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",136,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8802]],
                PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9999,
                    SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8805]],
                PARAMETER["False easting",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8806]],
                PARAMETER["False northing",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8807]]],
            CS[Cartesian,2],
                AXIS["northing (X)",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                AXIS["easting (Y)",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",6686]]],
    STEP[
        CONVERSION["Inverse of Medellin urban grid",
            METHOD["Inverse of Colombia Urban",
                ID["INVERSE(EPSG)",1052]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",6.22920888888889,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8801]],
            PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-75.5648869444444,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8802]],
            PARAMETER["False easting",835378.647,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8806]],
            PARAMETER["False northing",1180816.875,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8807]],
            PARAMETER["Projection plane origin height",1510,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",1039]],
            ID["INVERSE(EPSG)",6225]]],
    STEP[
        COORDINATEOPERATION["Ballpark geographic offset from MAGNA-SIRGAS to JGD2011",
            SOURCECRS[
                GEOGCRS["MAGNA-SIRGAS",
                    DATUM["Marco Geocentrico Nacional de Referencia",
                        ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                            ORDER[1],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                            ORDER[2],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    ID["EPSG",4686]]],
            TARGETCRS[
                GEOGCRS["JGD2011",
                    DATUM["Japanese Geodetic Datum 2011",
                        ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                            ORDER[1],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                            ORDER[2],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    ID["EPSG",6668]]],
            METHOD["Geographic2D offsets",
                ID["EPSG",9619]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude offset",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8601]],
            PARAMETER["Longitude offset",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8602]]]],
    STEP[
        CONVERSION["Japan Plane Rectangular CS zone XVIII",
            METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
                ID["EPSG",9807]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",20,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8801]],
            PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",136,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8802]],
            PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9999,
                SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
                ID["EPSG",8805]],
            PARAMETER["False easting",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8806]],
            PARAMETER["False northing",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8807]],
            ID["EPSG",17818]]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World"],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]]]
```

Comment: What are your GDAL and Proj versions? Could you also run this from command line `projinfo -s epsg:6257 -t epsg:6686`?

Comment: GDAL  3.0.2
proj  6.2.1

Comment: I added the report in edit.

Comment: Looks the same that I get. Does gdalwarp executable work `gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:6686 aoi1.tif aoi1_reproj.tif`?

Comment: Same error: ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_as_proj_string: Unsupported conversion method: Colombia Urban

ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_as_proj_string: Unsupported conversion method: Colombia Urban
ERROR 6: Cannot find coordinate operations from `EPSG:6257' to `EPSG:6686'

Comment: I cannot even convert to normal EPSG:4326

Comment: Perhaps `EPSG:6257` is unknown to your Proj version. Try to convert something from EPSG:4326 into EPSG:3857. If that fails also you must have a broken installation. But actually projinfo gives the same message for me `Error when exporting to PROJ string: Unsupported conversion method: Colombia Urban`. There may be something special in this projection. I recommend to write mail to gdal-dev mailing list. Include link to this question.

Comment: The 2nd definition is using the Esri name for the projection algorithm, which is the same as Colombia Urban. Can you just redefine the data's CRS instead?

Comment: I managed to define the projection of the raster in ArcMap, and export it with the epsg 6686. I will write the email to the gdal people. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer that was given in the gdal-dev mailing list:

> EPSG:6257 uses the "Colombia Urban" projection method, whose support
> has been  added only in PROJ 7.2 (
> https://proj.org/operations/projections/col_urban.html )
>
> And there must be an error in the target EPSG code in your post:
> EPSG:6686 is  a Japanese CRS (well, you could technically try to do
> the reprojection, but it  is unlikely this is what you want to do)